# Boto3 code unable to send the output through sns service

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to send the "emrStatusCheck" output to the SNS service. I'm able to print the output. However, when it is provided in the SNS service it results in the error message. Thank you in advance.

""Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Message, value: [\"Cluster_ID = 0000, Name_of_cluster = , status_of_cluster = RUNNING, Instance_Group = CORE, Market = ON_DEMAND, CreationDateTime = 2019-02-14 19:12:50.944000+00:00, NormalizedInstanceHours = 112, Autoscale = None, Assigned_tags = [{'Key': 'test', 'Value': 'test'}, {'Key': 'test', 'Value': 'test'}, {'Key': 'test', 'Value': 'test'}, {'Key': 'test', 'Value': 'test'}]\"], type: , valid types: ",

```
import boto3
import json
from datetime import timedelta

REGION = 'us-east-1'

Topic_Arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000:Lambd"

emrclient = boto3.client('emr', region_name=REGION)
snsclient = boto3.client('sns', region_name=REGION)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    EMRS = emrclient.list_clusters(
    ClusterStates = ['STARTING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING']
    )

clusters = EMRS["Clusters"]
for cluster_details in clusters :
    id = cluster_details.get("Id")

    describe_cluster = emrclient.describe_cluster(
        ClusterId = id
        )
    cluster_values = describe_cluster["Cluster"]
    name = cluster_values.get("Name")
    tag_val = cluster_values.get("Tags")
    Instancehours = cluster_values.get("NormalizedInstanceHours")


    emr_ig = emrclient.list_instance_groups(
     ClusterId = id
     )
    emrid = emr_ig["InstanceGroups"]
    for item in emrid :
        purchase_type = item.get("Market")
        instancegroup_id = item.get("Id")
        instancegroup_type = item.get("InstanceGroupType")
        status = item.get("Status")
        state = status.get("State")
        timeline = status.get("Timeline")
        autoscaling = item.get("AutoScalingPolicy", None)
        #autoscaling_status = autoscaling.get("Status")
        #autoscaling_state = autoscaling_status.get("State")
        create_date_time = timeline.get("CreationDateTime")
        ready_date_time = timeline.get("ReadyDateTime")
        emrdetails = "Cluster_ID = " + id + "," + " Name_of_cluster = " + name + "," + " status_of_cluster = " + state + "," + " Instance_Group = " + instancegroup_type + "," + " Market = " + purchase_type + "," + " CreationDateTime = " + str(create_date_time) + "," + " NormalizedInstanceHours = " + str(Instancehours) + "," + " Autoscale = " + str(autoscaling) + "," + " Assigned_tags = " + str(tag_val)
        emr_status_list = []
        emr_status_list.append(emrdetails)

        emrStatusCheck = []
        for emr_status in emr_status_list :
            if ((emr_status.split(",")[4]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("ON_DEMAND") and (emr_status.split(",")[3]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("CORE") or (emr_status.split(",")[7]).split("=")[1].strip() == str("None")):
                emrStatusCheck.append(emr_status)


        snsclient.publish(
            TopicArn =  Topic_Arn,
            Message = emrStatusCheck,
            Subject = "EMR Cluster Details",
            )
```

Comment: What is `EMR_values`? It doesn't seem to be defined?

Comment: Apologies, please check now. It's emrStatusCheck

Answer (score 0):

Your `emrStatusCheck` variable is a list, but the `Message` parameter requires a `string`.

You can convert it with:

```
json.dumps(emrStatusCheck)
```

See: [json — JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)

That's why it said "Invalid type for parameter Message".